# using negative exponents with bc in Bash

Tags: bash, exponent, bc

I'm having a difficulty with using negative exponents in the program `bc` in Bash. If I execute `echo "2*1.86929*10^05" | bc`, I get a result of `373858.00000` while if I execute `echo "2*1.86929*10^-05" | bc`, I get a result only of `0`. How can I get better accuracy when using negative exponents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the output of `bc` is rounded to an integer. To keep the decimal part of the result, use `bc -l`, like this:

```
$ echo "2*1.86929*10^-05" | bc -l
.00003738580000000000
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you very much for your assistance on this.

Comment: `bc -l` should be the default for `bc`, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the value of "scale" - so

```
scale=50
2*1.86929*10^-05
```

Gives .00003738580000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Thanks for your help on that. I got it working in the following way: ```echo "scale=50; 2*1.86929*10^-05" | bc```.